# Make it more obvious a tab is reloading in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I remember (or is it just my memory playing games?) long ago browsers used to white out the page when they started reload. As a software developer this really would be useful. How could I get Chrome not to keep the previous, outdated version in tab? Equivalent of close tab, open new tab, copy-paste the URL.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl + F5?

Answer (score -1):

you can:

1. Use incognito/inPrivate tab!
2. use ***"clear cache"*** extension from chrome webstore.
3. Enable ***"Clear cookies and site data when you quit Chrome"*** from
   "chrome://settings/cookies"
4. If you want to clear data for one website go to **content settings** **"chrome://settings/content/all"** and choose clear data for this website

Comment: Neither this allows clearing cache for a single page.